# How to update recycler view item from realm response

Tags: android, realm

In my app i'm saving all data into realm now here when data is loaded into recycler view in my recycler view item i'm having a button there on click of button i'm setting the status field bool of realm database to true and thereafter on dataset changed i'm trying to set an item button background if boolean inside database is true but here i'm having no luck whenever my recyclerview is refreshed in not getting my desired output maybe something is wrong with my data fetching query any help will be appreciated.

Here is my recycler view on bindview holder code:

```
//this is the code where i'm facing problem i want the else want to execute but that's not happening
val `object` = realm!!.where(Devicesdatabase::class.java).equalTo("status", false).findFirst()
if (`object` != null) {
    holder.btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_button)
    holder.btn.text = "Stranger"
}
else
{
    holder.btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_button_grey)
        holder.btn.setText("known")
}
```

Here's what i'm doing inside on button click:

```
holder.btn.setOnClickListener {
    holder.btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_button_grey)
    holder.btn.setText("known")
    val `object` = realm!!.where(Devicesdatabase::class.java)
            .equalTo("devicename", host.hostname)
            .findFirst()
    if (`object` != null) {
        realm!!.executeTransaction {
            var item = realm!!.createObject(Devicesdatabase::class.java)
            item.status = true
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }
}
```

This is my realm model class:

```
@RealmClass
open class Devicesdatabase : RealmModel {
    var wifi:String?=null
    var devicename: String? = null
    var macAddress: String? = null
    var status:Boolean = false
    var type:String?=null
}
```

Comment: yes it's kotlin var is nothing but just a variable like String object but in this case converted form to java is something like DevicesDatabase object = realm.where(Devicesdatabase.java)

Comment: you are creating an object, setting it's `status` but not it's `devicename` (don't know if it'll solve your problem)